# UITableViewController pull to refresh with a frozen header

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I have a mockup that looks like this:

[image: mockup1]

This is all one big Table Controller that you can scroll.

When the section header hits the top of the page it freezes along the top, like so:

[image: mockup2]

Which is working fine. However, when you go back to the top and do a pull to refresh, I want it to do this:

[image]

So the pull to refresh dialog appears between the top table header cell and the section header (that is no longer frozen).

Is this possible? I haven't found an implementation like this in my searches.

Comment: If you want to do so then you will then to add the pull to refresh within the section header itself and make sure that there is always at least one section in the table and pulling the tableview should add the activity view and then remove after certain time.

Comment: Your best bet is to create a `UIViewController` and add the table header yourself as a `UIView`, and then add a `UITableView` underneath it. Then link it and employ the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol (later adding your 'pull to refresh' add-on).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to achieve this,

1. Add a `UIScrollView` as the subview of `UIViewController's` view.
2. Add a `UIView` and `UITableView` as the subview of this scroll view
3. `UIView` inside scroll view represents table header cell.
4. Section header can be the header of `UITableview` and table contents represents the `UITableView's` cells.
5. Add `UIRefreshControl` as subview of `UITableView` and set its target method.
6. Implement the scrollview delegate `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` for both `UITableview` and `UIScrollview`.
7. When you are scrolling the tableview, move the parent scrollview whenever the table view header moves in the upward direction till the header reaches the top. Add an if condition in scrollview delegate to check for this.
8. When the table view is moved the downward direction, move the parent scrollview until the `UIView` table cell header is visible after this stop scrolling of `UIScrollview` and allow table view to scroll. This will enable the `UIRefreshControl`.

Here the key thing is the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method and how you implement the scrolling. You can add a check for `contentOffset` to determine how much tableview and scrollview has been scrolled. In order to restrict the scrolling you can manually set this value in this delegate method to a particular value and it wont scroll after that.